# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25

Tags: android

I just switched laptops and try to import an Android project to the new Android Studio installation. I've installed the Android Support Libary and Repository.... it cannot be found though?

I've also just one SDK - the Android Studio app.

Any ideas?

22:47:31 Failed to refresh Gradle project 'LabsCore'
         Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25.
         Required by:
         LabsCoreProject:LabsCore:unspecified
         Search in build.gradle files

Comment: What SDK versions do you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

Play Services is in the Google Repository, not the Android Support Repository. Install the former and you should be good to go.